# Can't access filab instance virtual machine

Tags: fiware, filab

I have a problem accessing our filab instance Virtual Machine through SSH. I have created the keypair pem file,  the instance, associate IP and create security groups without incidences but I can't access it (always timeout).

The FILAB CLOUD Dashboard status is ACTIVE and RUNNING

All appears to be correct but I can't access. Does anyone know why?

Comment: This is a programming forum. You should take this question to the infrastructure themed forums where there will be people willing to help you.

Comment: Sorry if this is not the best place for the question. I have found here answers for other configuration related problems with filab.

Comment: @Micho FIWARE has specifically said that they will be active on StackOverflow to handle questions. Furthermore, there are a bazillion framework-related questions on SO? You think they don't have place here?

Comment: @Maarten See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
"Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools."

Answer (score 0):

All questions related to insfrastructure administration in FIWARE should be sent by mail to fiware-lab-help@lists.fiware.org.